# A way of checking if javascript files are loading in order?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, frontend, backend

I understand that if I have a js file (`x.js`) that has some function and another file (`y.js`) that uses the function from `x.js` then when loading the files, I must load x`.js` then `y.js`

In bigger projects, 1) is there a way - i.e. editor tool, plugin, console tool, website - that checks if JS files are loaded in the right order? or 2) is there a standardized method of checking the order of JS file load?

I picked up* a huge project last week at work and sometimes the main page loads correctly with no console errors, other times I get a number of console errors.

*The project had many parts in the past, but right now they cut it down to one part. However, the JS files have way too many dependencies and the person who worked before me did not bother cleaning the files, marking unused functions, or even commenting.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can mark the scripts that have dependencies as `defer` so they won't load until other scripts load first. From the [html5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#script):

> If the element has a src attribute, and the element has a defer
>   attribute, and the element has been flagged as "parser-inserted", and
>   the element does not have an async attribute The element must be added
>   to the end of the list of scripts that will execute when the document
>   has finished parsing associated with the Document of the parser that
>   created the element.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. I don't understand why someone down-voted the question.

Comment: what if some of those dependencies are dependant on each other ... defer wont help - unless the defered dependencies are in the right order I guess :p (bring on modern ES modules)